# How to compare id of two tables and when they are equal add a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have to verify the "***number_id***" in a column that contains a list of ids from **table 1** and create a new column with a list of control number from the ***table 2***.

I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd 

table_1 = pd.read_excel('path/file.xlsx', sheet_name="sheet 1")
table_2 = pd.read_excel('path/file.xlsx', dtype='str')

table_1[['Number_id_table_1']].head(5)

        Number_id_table_1
    0   [35904690, 20344131]
    1   [26360006]
    2   NaN
    3   [46780790]
    4   [355343]

table_2.head()

    control     account_id_nk
0   71996761124 10197651
1   49991227097 1263884
2   71981020953 876828
3   11964723845 35661849
4   47992004868 19071134
```

To campare the values and add the control number I am doing:

```
from itertools import chain

def mapping_account_id(index, original_df, column_id_name = str()):
    original_index = index
    list_column_id = []
    if original_index in original_df:
        for ind in original_index:
            list_column_id.append(original_df.iloc[original_index][column_id_name])
            return list(set(list(chain(*list_column_id))))
    else:
        return None

table_1 ['Number_id_table_1_teste'] = table_1 ['Number_id_table_1'].apply(mapping_account_id, args = (table_2, 'control'))
```

The result is "None" for every row. But i know that the values exist in the table.

```
Number_id_table_1_teste
0   None
1   None
2   None
3   None
4   None
```

I expected the column "***Number_id_table_1_teste***" to contain the ***control*** number for each ***number_id***.

```
Number_id_table_1_teste
0   [21964258763, 81999403136]
1   [92993930352]
2   NaN
3   [17996018821]
4   [85988943884]
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: `Number_id_table_1_teste`
`0   [21964258763, 81999403136]`
`1   [92993930352]`
`2   NaN`
`3   [17996018821]`
`4   [85988943884]`

Comment: Can you post that back into the question, with the formatting?

Comment: Can you add `axis=1` to your `.apply` function as parameter and re-try?

Comment: I tried to include `axis=1` but is giving `SyntaxError`. Can you write an example how to do this, please.